# offset converting float to uchar in cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

In process of speeding up some processes (can't name them, sorry), I tried to create a

```
cv::Mat_<uchar> discretization;
```

Now when I get a depth map in float

```
cv::Mat_<float> depth_map;
discretization = depth_map / resolution_mtr;
```

where resolution_mtr is a float. Its value is 0.1 currently.
When I do this, for a value say, 0.48 in depth map , I get the discretization value of 5. My understanding says it should be 4 . I guess it is round off to nearest uchar. Is there a way out of this without getting into for loop ? 
Basically I want to use floor values in discretization and not round off .

Comment: why do you want to assign the result of floating point division to `uchar`?

Comment: basically its a way of binning values for speeding up further process

Comment: I can use int, but I don't expect that to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Why not define an inherited class CvNoRoundMat and override its operator+ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract 0.5 from the result.

This code

```
float resolution_mtr = 0.1;
float vals[] = {0.48, 0.4, 0.38, 0.31};
cv::Mat_<float> depth_map(1,4,vals);
cv::Mat_<uchar> discretization( depth_map  / resolution_mtr - 0.5);

std::cout << "depth_map: " << depth_map << std::endl;
std::cout << "discretization: " << discretization << std::endl;
```

will give you following results:

```
depth_map: [0.47999999, 0.40000001, 0.38, 0.31]
discretization: [4, 4, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Yeah but depth_map has Nan's and 0 vals as well. And with 0, the result would be wrong. Otherwise, duh! why didn't I think of that !

Comment: I see problem only with nan, With 0 it works fine as int(0.0/0.1-0.5) = int(-0.5) = 0